# Share a Project to SVN that Already Exists in SVN

Tags: svn

I am working on a offline (not connected to svn ) version of a workspace. Now I want to sync this workspace to SVN (these projects already exists on SVN).

If I did `right click -> share project` , then the result with me was: the projects were in sync with repository , but all my files were over written by those in the repository. (I don't want this)

I don't want any sort of automatic update/commit to take place. I want to link my project with the repository than sync it up and do a manual check-in or check-out by resolving conflicts. As I want to check-in some files that are there in workspace and to check-out some others.

Please suggest some approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solve this situation is as follows:

1. First check-out the repository as a new project.
2. Copy all files your project into the just crated project where you just have checked-out the repository. In case of file conflicts overwrite the existing files. I would recommend you to **perform the copy operation not within Eclipse**, better to do this with your system file browser (e.g. Explorer on Windows).
3. Execute *Refresh* on the new project, all changes should now be visible within the project and you can use *Compare to -> Base version* for identifying the differences.
4. If all modifications are ready you can commit your changes.

Comment: Robert,

if i follow that approach , i can sync my workspace to svn. but actual projects in my workspace wont b linked to svn , right ? 
that is just a way to commit my changes to svn ? 

I am on a offline workspace and i want to connect it to svn , as a usual workspace that is checked out of svn would be.. is this possible ? :/

Comment: I have never seen that a whole workspace is checked-in into an SVN. You always only check-in the projects separately.

Comment: yes you are right, probably i wasnt clear in my words. 
actually i`ll explain complete scenario . I use svn plugins on eclipse to link projects in my workspace to svn. 
the approach u suggesting. checkout the svn, than replace files from local to that project and do a checkin. 
Firstly i have some good 200-250 files that would require to be replaced.

Is there no way to just linkup existing projects in my eclipse workspace to SVN ? so i could synchronize it using the plugin and indivisualy cherry pick each file and resolve confilcts ?

Comment: +1 , i know i am late on voting up but have just started getting involved at stackoverflow